# LFTP Transfer a directory thats still being uploaded

Tags: linux, ftp

Is it possible to transfer a directory from a remote server that is still being uploaded to using LFTP?

Each week I have to transfer out files from a directory that may still be in use. I always end up running lftp multiple times if all the files are not present because it assumes no more files are going to be uploaded at the time its run. I tried running cron jobs but I'm really after a solution that's more instantaneous. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LFTP has an option called --loop that allows the mirror dir to be repeated until no changes are found. This sorted my issue.